# Changing dropdownlist based on another dropdownlist using jQuery in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, new SelectList(Model._listAllStateVModel.ListAllStates, "Abbreviations", "Name"), "Select.....", new { ..... })
```

---

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.County, new SelectList(Model._listAllCountyVModel.ListAllCounty, "CountyId", "CountyName"), "Select.....", new { ..... })
```

I have list of states in `DropDownListFor(model => model.State)` & list of counties in `DropDownListFor(model => model.County) + the word "Other..."`,
what i want is when i select Any State other than Texas DropDownListFor County has to change to the word "Other..".
how can I do this using jQuery???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work fine.....

```
 $('#State').change(function () {
    if ($('#State option:selected').text() != 'Texas') {
        $('#County').val('Other').attr("selected", "selected");
    }
    else {
        $('#County').val(null).attr("selected", "selected");
    }
});
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<select Id="State">
  <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
  <option value="Sidney">Sidney</option>
  <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
</select>
<select Id="Country">
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

$('#State').change(function() {
    if ($('#State option:selected').text() != 'Texas') {
        $('#Country').val("Other").attr("selected", "selected");
    }
    else{
        $('#Country').val("USA").attr("selected", "selected");
    }
})
```

You can also check for value instead of text

Comment: this code is not working,it's changing County to blank

Comment: $("#State").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() != "Texas") {
                    $("#County").val("Other");
                }
            })

Comment: I have updated code for the same. Please check it. JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lwdmbn33/